# Django TastyPie PUT Nested User Model Correctly

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I'm trying to go with-the-grain using Django TastyPie to update my models.  I have an Identity model, acting as a wrapper around default Django user model:

```
class Identity(ProfileBase):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='identity')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_upload_path, blank=True,
        null=True)
```

I have my `UserResource`:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'user'
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        include_resource_uri = False
```

And I have my `IdentityResource`:

```
class IdentityResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user', full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'identity'
        queryset = Identity.objects.select_related()
        fields = ['user', 'avatar']
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False

        authentication = OAuthTokenAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

I'm currently successfully updating first_name, last_name using the ModelResource `obj_update` method within `IdentityResource`:

```
def obj_update(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
    print 'updating object'
    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)
    bundle.obj.user = request.user
    user = bundle.data['user']
    bundle.obj.user.first_name = user['first_name']
    bundle.obj.user.last_name = user['last_name']
    return super(IdentityResource, self).obj_update(bundle, request, user=request.user)
```

**I want to make a `PUT` request and optionally update any field on the user or identity models (first_name, last_name on user, or the avatar field on identity).** I would rather not have to manually access each field from the bundle data and set them on models manually, as I have done above.

How can I do this naturally in TastyPie?  Can someone explain a better approach to solving this problem?  Any direction is GREATLY appreciated. :)

Comment: I have set a bounty, so the question hopefully will gain more attention and someone will provide the answer that could be then treated as canonical (hopefully). Many people were hitting similar problem, as this is standard practice in Django to handle user information extensions that way (by adding new model in relation one-to-one to User model). People just need to remember about one additional thing: the signal that is usually used with this solution and automatically creates Identity / UserProfile instance assigned to User instance.

Comment: Isnt creating a User from a relation like this risky? How would you setup Passwords and notify them? I would stay away from writing generic solutions like that because they can lead to security issues downstream.

Comment: It looks like you are updating currently logged in user. Is that on purpose? I doubt it.

Comment: Is obj_update the wrong place to be updating a currently logged in user's account?  This is not for creating a new user in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my shot at providing an answer that attempts to leverage Tastypie as much as possible.

It is a little more generic than the OP's request (it will update any user, not just the one logged in). In the real world you would probably want to add some sort of authentication/authorization.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.account.models import Identity

class IdentityResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Identity.objects.all()


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_list_methods = ['get']
        allowed_detail_methods = ['get','put']
        authorization = Authorization()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        identity_bundle = self.build_identity_bundle(bundle)
        identity_bundle = IdentityResource().full_dehydrate(identity_bundle)
        return identity_bundle

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
        user_bundle = super(UserResource, self).obj_update(bundle, request, **kwargs)
        identity_bundle = self.build_identity_bundle(user_bundle)
        IdentityResource().obj_update(identity_bundle, request)
        return user_bundle

    def build_identity_bundle(self, user_bundle):
        identity_bundle = IdentityResource().build_bundle(
                obj=user_bundle.obj.get_profile(),
                data=user_bundle.data
            )
        return identity_bundle
```

What the example supports is:

- GET a flattened User+Identity resource
- PUT a flattened User+Identity resource, updating both models

You would want to register the UserResource in the API, and probably not the IdentityResource.

Comment: Sorry so late, but awesome answer.  I've got it working another way but am thinking I'll refactor what I've got to follow all the lovely Tastypie methods you're leveraging.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
# Find all properties in user model.
properties = [prop for prop in bunder.obj.user if not prop.startswith('__')]
bundle_user = bundle.data['user']
# Find the property in bundle user and set it back on user if it exists.
for property in properties:
  if property in bundle_user:
    setattr(bundle.obj.user, property, bundle_user[property])
```

Comment: You are trying to iterate over the model instance, not even checking if it is a field or method, or constant. There is a way to get the list of fields in the resource, which takes field exclusion into account.

Comment: Fundamol thank you for the suggestion, this isn't a terrible approach. @Tadeck, can you provide what you speak of here?

Comment: @kyleturner: Maybe not terrible, but not very reusable. The features I am talking about are: [`Resource.Meta.fields`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#fields), [`Resource.Meta.excludes`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#excludes), [`Resource.get_fields()`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#get-fields) and a little more... The issue here is that this answer does not use it, and does not clearly state that it already has been used before (eg. by TastyPie itself).

Comment: @Tadeck Fair point. I was trying to unblock with a answer, not necessarily one with TastyPie. I had used something similar but not in TastyPie so thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing the point but did you try a `PATCH`-method request? Tastypie will take all the sent attributes and update them in the database leaving all not-send attributes untouched.